# How to fit curtain poles so they won't be pulled down by children?

Tags: curtain-rail

I am putting up a curtain across a large gap, to separate two rooms in my open plan house. I'm concerned about the weight of the curtains combined with children passing through it everyday and don't want to see it pulled down.

It's 4.6kg for the curtain + pole.  Walls are brick and plaster board.

What type of fixing will a strong enough?
Will normal screws + rawl plugs be strong enough or they will just get pulled out once some weight is put on them?

Comment: Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @isherwood Fair enough.  Is that generic enough?

Comment: That's better, but now it's pretty opinion-based unless you supply even more info (e.g. length of gap).

Comment: Although I kind of agree with the answers most curtain rods have wimpy mounting brackets. Your challenge will be to find some heavy duty brackets and anchor them in the header for the opening. By header I do mean the brick with a sleeved anchor.

Answer (score 1):

"It's 4.6kg for the curtain + pole" **+ a hundred pounds of children** (or one or more idiot adults). That calls for steel pipe and [structural pipe base](https://www.grainger.com/product/4NXR6?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3O-3-dqk6AIVov_jBx290QUGEAYYBSABEgI1O_D_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMI3O-3-dqk6AIVov_jBx290QUGEAYYBSABEgI1O_D_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!284618243451!!!g!540448928863!), preferably threaded and not setscrew, 1" or larger, with long enough masonry screws to embed 1" into the masonry.

If it's in a 'curtain catalogue', that's not good enough. If it needs to not fall down, then it needs to be able to take me doing pull-ups on it, which is a base prerequisite for anything I mount in a home.

If it's not going to be, then it *should* be flimsy enough that falling on someone's head won't definitely kill them. If it isn't going to be flimsy, then you'd better mount-the-shit-out-of-it. It basically is a pull-up/grab bar, and some poor sod is going to use it as such eventually.

[image]

Comment: May need to cut away the plaster to attach directly to brick if it's furred-out; you'll find out when it crushes the plaster.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot here.
The variables are the width of the gap, the surface you are attaching to, the weight of the curtain (4.6kg) and your ability to keep the kids from swinging on them.
I'll assume your doorway is double width, 5 feet or so. You described the walls as "brick and plaster board". If you are attaching to brick using [expansion type fasteners](https://www.concretefasteners.com/diy-articles-brick-anchors/) it'll require some heavy drilling but the brackets you put up should be very secure. If the door is framed in wood, some good wood screws will do it. If you're going into drywall within the door frame the 2x door framing behind the drywall will give you sufficient support with normal wood screws.
The key here is the width of the door. Even at 5 feet (abt 1.5m) with a 4.6kg curtain you'll probably want to support the rod at the center with a hanger which should be available at most hardware or drapery stores where you bought the rod. If the door is a lot wider you may have to go to two hanging supports or more. Good luck with the kids.

Answer (score 0):

there's genrally lots of wood near a door in a plaster wall,  the bigger the door the more wood there is.

Find the wood and attach your rod brackets through the plaster to the wood.

Expanding plugs do tend to pull out of brick. Expanding bolts tend to outlast the brick, some are avaiable with countersunk heads (so externally they look like screws),

there are also those brick screws that are pretty good.